# How do I pass parameters to the controller in $routeProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular.js ....Based on the id, the fullPostController gets the required data using $http, but how am I supposed to pass the postId to the controller?

```
   'use strict';

var myAPP = angular.module('myAPP', [ 'ngRoute' ]);

myAPP.config(['$routeProvider',
    function (
        $routeProvider
    ) {
          $routeProvider.
              when('/', {
                  templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
                  controller: 'mainController'
              }).
             when('/post/:postId', {
                  templateUrl: 'pages/full_post.html',
                  controller: 'fullPostController'

              }).
              otherwise({
                  redirectTo: '/'
              });
}]);
```

How do I pass the postId to fullPostController??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inject $routeParams in the controller, the post id is $routeParams.postId